# Reset a boolean property back after a XAML animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got the following situation in a WPF application:

- I've some data pushed from a socket that can be new item or edited ones.
- When an item is updated I've to have the row to blink, this is actually performed using a boolean property IsChanged
- I've the following DataTrigger

  ```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewCell}" x:Key="Style">
  <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChanged}" Value="True">
          <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
              <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Highlight" />
              <BeginStoryboard Name="Highlight">
                  <Storyboard>
                      <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:03" From="Red" FillBehavior="Stop" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
                  </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
          </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
      </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
  ```

The following style is applied to each row of a RadGridView using a CellStyleSelector. Currently, but I consider it as an HACK I've got an interface that reset the value to false

```
 public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
 {
       if (item is INotifyUpdate notifyUpdate)
       {
            //First I check if the cell has to blink
            if (notifyUpdate.IsChanged)
            {
                notifyUpdate.IsChanged = false;
            }

           ...
        }
```

- My problem is that I've to perform this hack to reset the value at false, otherwise it's set as true and never reverted back. As result when another row is updated and the grid is refreshed I got the rows that have been updated to blink again.

Is there a way I can have the false value set back to false?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a custom `IsChanged` property, you could create an `EventTrigger` for a `Binding.TargetUpdated` event and start your animation there.

Something like:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <!-- your animation here -->
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Don't forget to set `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True` for the `Binding` you would like to observe.

So you won't need the "unnecessary" `IsChanged` property at all. The desired animation will be triggered just when the `Binding` updates the target value.

Comment: excuse me but what happens on the first load, when initially all the data are loaded?

Comment: Then you'll see all the animations. If you don't want to, use an attached property or a `Behavior` to initially set the `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` property to `false`.

Comment: can you please provide me a sample? the NotifyOnTargetUpdated should be set on each bind?